# com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException Public Key Retrieval is not allowed

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I'm presently learning Servlets and Jsp via a video tutorial, I am trying to connect to MySql database but its been difficult doing so, I have followed all steps taken in the tutorial but its still not connecting, at first the exception i was getting was the  java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for com.mysql.jdbc.Driver at java.sql.DriverManager

i have checked online for a possible solution but none is working for me, right now i added MySQL-connector-java-5.1.49-bin.jar to the lib and its bringing another type of exception.

```
 java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Public Key Retrieval is not allowed)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:669)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:544)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:753)
    at com.luv2code.web.jdbc.TextSerlets.doGet(TextSerlets.java:43)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:690)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:373)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1590)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Public Key Retrieval is not allowed
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:403)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:919)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:898)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:887)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:861)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:878)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:874)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.proceedHandshakeWithPluggableAuthentication(MysqlIO.java:1770)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1217)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2189)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2220)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2015)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:768)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:403)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:385)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:323)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.DriverConnectionFactory.createConnection(DriverConnectionFactory.java:55)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.PoolableConnectionFactory.makeObject(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:355)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.validateConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:115)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:665)
    ... 27 more
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Public Key Retrieval is not allowed
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:403)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:919)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:898)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:887)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:861)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.authentication.CachingSha2PasswordPlugin.nextAuthenticationStep(CachingSha2PasswordPlugin.java:130)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.proceedHandshakeWithPluggableAuthentication(MysqlIO.java:1768)
    ... 44 more
```

I'm kinda getting frustrated as its affecting my learning progress,below is my context.xml file and i must also say that its now showing some kind of multiple annotation found at this line error which is in line 1.

```
<Context>

  <Resource name="jdbc/web_student_tracker" 
            auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
               maxActive="20" maxIdle="5" maxWait="10000"
               username="webstudent" password="webstudent" 
               driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
               url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/web_student_tracker?useSSL=false"/>

</Context>
```

My servlet code:

```
package com.luv2code.web.jdbc;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;

import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class TextSerlets
 */
@WebServlet("/TextSerlets")
public class TextSerlets extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Resource(name="jdbc/web_student_tracker")
    private DataSource dataSource;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        //step 1 : Set up print writer
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        response.setContentType("text/plain");

        //step 2: Get a cinnection to the adatbase
        Connection myConn = null;
        Statement myStmt = null;
        ResultSet myRs = null;


        try {
            myConn = dataSource.getConnection();

            //Step 3 :Create a SQL statement
            String sql = "select * from student";
            myStmt = myConn.createStatement();

            //step 4: Execute SQL query
            myRs = myStmt.executeQuery(sql);

            //step 5 : Process the result set
            while (myRs.next()) {
                String email = myRs.getString("email");
                out.println(email);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exc) {
            exc.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

This is my first time posting here so kindly ignore any error made on the post if there's any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i deleted the total web project an created a new one and it seems to be working fine now with this `url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/web_student_tracker?useSSL=false"`

Answer (score 0):

You should add `allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true` to allow the client to automatically request the public key from the server. Note that `allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true` is not recommended as it could allow a malicious proxy to perform a MITM attack to get the plaintext password. Change

```
url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/web_student_tracker?useSSL=false"
```

to

```
url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/web_student_tracker?allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&useSSL=false;"
```

Comment: when i tried this i got an error saying  The reference to entity "useSSL" must end with the ';' delimiter....but when i tried this   url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/web_student_tracker"/>  it worked but it cam with this at the console :        Mon May 18 14:47:53 BST 2020 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL.....

Comment: @TimiCruz Can you please try adding ; after useSSL=false.
"jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/web_student_tracker?allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&useSSL=false;"
Also your "public key retrieval" issue is resolved right?

Comment: its still the same url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/web_student_tracker?allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&useSSL=false;"/>  Also i am unable to know if the  "public key retrieval" issue is solved as i am unable to run it with the error showing the red mark below = ...like i said before when i tried this url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/web_student_tracker"/> it worked but came with the warning WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended.

Comment: It's not the same URL, now we are adding a semicolon to the end.
What issue are you facing on using the new URL? Please share the exception log

Comment: So i deleted the total web project an created a new one and it seems to be working fine now with this url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/web_student_tracker?useSSL=false" ....Is that it or should i be worried about future errors?

Comment: I am not sure Why you are not getting "Public key retrieval" error, that you were facing earlier. Ideally, you should add allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true as part of URL as suggested in the answer. However, it's your call, please feel free to upvote/accept the answer if that helped and solved your problem. Thanks

Comment: Well i tried adding it again to see but its still brings the : The reference to entity "useSSL" must end with the ';' delimiter...so i guess i will live it the way it is since its working fine now...thanks